# Why I didn't initialize database?

Tags: nodeos, multi-index, chainbase

I want to add the my multi_index in controller db.

And Finally Adding all class is set up. But When eos program initialize the database, it didn't work.

my error log :

```
/eos/libraries/chainbase/include/chainbase/chainbase.hpp:188:27: error: 
  type 'index_type' (aka 'int') cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no
  members
     typedef typename index_type::value_type                       value_type;
```

My multi_index class :

```
using setw_multi_index = chainbase::shared_multi_index_container<
      s_object,
      indexed_by<
          ordered_unique<tag<by_id>, member<s_object, s_object::id_type, &s_object::id>>,
          ordered_unique<tag<by_keyBox>, composite_key<s_object,
                    member<s_object, block_num_type, &s_object::blockNum>,
                    member<s_object, uint8_t, &s_object::Flags>,
                    member<s_object, std::string, &s_object::strDetKey>>>>>;
```

And initiate the database :

```
db.create<setw_multi_index>([](auto &){});
```

what is wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Add `struct by_keyBox;` before using declaration:

```
struct by_keyBox;

using setw_multi_index = chainbase::shared_multi_index_container<
      s_object,
      indexed_by<
          ordered_unique<tag<by_id>, member<s_object, s_object::id_type, &s_object::id>>,
          ordered_unique<tag<by_keyBox>, composite_key<s_object,
                    member<s_object, block_num_type, &s_object::blockNum>,
                    member<s_object, uint8_t, &s_object::Flags>,
                    member<s_object, std::string, &s_object::strDetKey>>>>>;
```

Comment: But I had already been set that.. I thought when my branch was merged, it caused the problem. So now I am solved it. Thank you for your reply!